# karate API how to capture a response value to pass as request to another API

Tags: karate

Capture the response field from one API call and send that as an input parameter to another API call

```
Given url petStoreUrl
And request {  "id": 1, "category": {"id": 0 ,"name": "golden doodle" },"name": "scooby", "photoUrls": ["string"], "tags": [{ "id": 0,"name": "scooby"}],"status": "available" }
When method post


{ "id": 9199424981609294382, "category": { "id": 0, "name": "golden doodle" }, "name": "scooby1", "photoUrls": [ "string" ], "tags": [ { "id": 0, "name": "scooby" } ], "status": "available" }
```

i want to send the response id `"id": 9199424981609294382` from the above call as an input parameter to this get request
path/id

Answer (score 2):

You really need to read the documentation. The ["hello world" example](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hello-world) itself shows you how to do this.

```
Given path response.id
When method get
```

Read this section carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#url